# How to Vectorize this calculation in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a dataframe and a dictionary.  The dictionary holds integers, with a different integer per key.  There is a column in the dataframe that holds those keys.  I have been trying to improve my scripts' speed by vectorizing when possible.  Because now, I am iterrows of the dataframe.  How could I vectorize this?

Dictionary: `Dict = {Words1:[20,10],Words2:[10,20],Words3:[30,50]}`

Dataframe:

```
  Col1      Col2
'Words1'    Yes
'Words2'    No
'Words3'    Yes
```

I tried:
`df['Col3'] = Dict[df['Col1']][1]`.  Since you are laughing, you know it did not work.

What I want to do is:

1. Take the second value in the dictionary and put it in Col3 as per the key in Col1.
2. I will then take that Col3 and compute a final number in Col4 based upon if word is Yes/No in Col2:

   a) If its Yes, I will add to the number in Col3

   b) If it's no, I will subtract from the number in Col3.

I really appreciate the help.

Comment: What do you want to add or subtract to the number in Col 3?

Comment: I will be adding/subtracting Another column with Col3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Col1':['Words1','Words2','Words3'],
    'Col2':['Yes','No','Yes'],
    'vals':[1,2,3]})
my_dict = {'Words1':[20,10],'Words2':[10,20],'Words3':[30,50]}
val = 3
```

The first part can be solved using map with a pretreated dict

```
reduced_dict = { k : my_dict[k][1] for k in my_dict}
df['Col3'] = df['Col1'].map(reduced_dict)
```

The second part can be cheesed by mapping `Col2` to a sign and multiplying it by the value to add/subtract `val`

```
df['Col4'] = df['Col3'] + df.Col2.map({'Yes':1,'No':-1})*val
```

Note that this also works if the value to add/subtract is part of the dataframe

```
df['Col4'] = df['Col3'] + df.Col2.map({'Yes':1,'No':-1})*df.vals
```